# Pass data from HTTP POST create method to view using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to filter a list of airports based on the country that the user selected. I only want to show the airports that are present in the country. I have a view where I am displaying the two drop down lists:

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@using WebApplication1.Controllers
@model Country

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<h2>Airport List</h2>
@Html.Label("Airports", "Airports")
<select name="Airports">
    @foreach (var airport in ViewBag.EuropeanAirports)
    {
    <option value="@(airport.name)">@(airport.name)</option>
    }
</select>

@Html.Label("Country", "Country")


@Html.DropDownListFor(c =>c.country, new SelectList(ViewBag.countries, "country", "country"), "Select Country")
```

}

Here is the code in my controller, I am using the get of the create method to populate my drop down lists and I am using the post to retrieve the country that was selected by the user. I am using LINQ queries to retrieve the given airports in one single country since I have two JSON files, one for the countries' list and another one for the airports' list. Here is the code that I have in my controller:
        // GET METHOD 
       public ActionResult Create()
        {

```
        //LINQ QUERY TO RETRIEVE ALL EUROPEAN AIRPORTS 
        IEnumerable<Airport> EuropeanAirports = from n in airports
                       where n.continent.Equals("EU")
                       select n;
        IEnumerable<Country> countries = GetCountries();
        ViewBag.countries = countries;
        ViewBag.EuropeanAirports = EuropeanAirports; 
        return View(new Country());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Country postedCountry)
    {
        IEnumerable<Country> countries = GetCountries();
        string selectedCountry = postedCountry.country;
        var abbreviation = from n in countries
                           where n.country.Equals(selectedCountry)
                           select n.abbr;
        IEnumerable<Airport> EuropeanAirports = from n in airports
                                                where 
                                       n.iso.Equals(abbreviation)
                                                select n;
        ViewBag.EuropeanAirports = EuropeanAirports;
        return View(EuropeanAirports);
    }
```

Here are the JSON files that I am working on:

Countries JSON file: 
     [

```
 {
"country": "Iceland",
"abbr": "IS"
},
{
"country": "Kosovo",
"abbr": "KS"
},
...
]
```

Airports JSON:

```
  [
  {
    "iata": "UTK",
    "lon": "169.86667",
    "iso": "MH",
    "status": 1,
    "name": "Utirik Airport",
    "continent": "OC",
    "type": "airport",
    "lat": "11.233333",
    "size": "small"
  },
...
  ]
```

My goal is to filter the content of the airports drop down list depending on the country that was chosen by the end user. As you can tell from my controller, I have tried to obtain the list of the airports that are specific to that country but I do not really know how to transfer that information to the view and update the content of the airport drop down list. I guess I would have to use AJAX to do that and I am not really familiar with it. I am doing all the filtering of the airports in the HTTP POST of the create method in my controller and I don't really know if that's legal and I don't know how to retrieve all that info in my view and populate my drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change your drop down list (select list) value whenever the selected country changes, then you really need good old ajax. Here's a simple JQUERY implementation.

VIEW MODEL:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Airport> Airports { get; set; }

    public CreateViewModel() {}
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{   
    //LINQ QUERY TO RETRIEVE ALL EUROPEAN AIRPORTS 
    IEnumerable<Airport> europeanAirports = from n in airports
                   where n.continent.Equals("EU")
                   select n;
    IEnumerable<Country> countries = GetCountries();

    CreateViewModel viewModel = new CreateViewModel();
    viewModel.Countries = countries;
    viewModel.Airports = europeanAirports;

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCountryAirports(string countryCode)
{
    // Get the airports you need
    IEnumerable<Airport> airports = null;

    return Json(airports, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

VIEW:

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@using WebApplication1.Controllers
@model Country

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) // Do not know what this is for
{
    <h2>Airport List</h2>
    @Html.Label("Airports", "Airports")
    @Html.DropDownList("Airports", new SelectList(Model.Airports, "id", "name"), new { @class = "form-control" }) // id is the value when selected, name is the text displayed. Change as needed.
    @Html.Label("Country", "Country")
    @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Model.Countries, "id", "name"), "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control" }) // id is the value when selected, name is the text displayed. Change as needed.
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Country").change(function(){
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCountryAirports", "Action")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                countryId: countryId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "";

                // markup += "<option value=''></option>"; Uncomment if you want to add a blank option

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[i].id + ">" + data[i].name + "</option>"; // Change id and name to correct properties
                }

                $("#Airports").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#Airports").empty();
                $("#Airports").val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```